# Dealing with supervisor time theft

Tags: professionalism

Supervisor is exempt, salaried, in the United States. This supervisor has the power to edit punches for payroll, and does so to perpetuate perfect clock-ins/outs on a weekly basis among many sick days (way more than the company would allow a generic employee), and despite often late in/early out most days. Said supervisor also somehow maintains a supervisor level while only performing duties everyone is already doing. Higher-level supervisors seem to be oblivious or lax about the situation, but it seems like this supervisor continues to make advances in taking advantage of this.  I'm technically supervised by the person above this manager.

Now, most opinion I can find myself says essentially don't complain about anyone higher on the food chain than you, and the situation will resolve itself eventually if it's really as bad as you think it is. Would letting the situation resolve itself be the correct course of action?

Comment: It has nothing to do with you. You are not his manager. He may have a different contract. He may be working from home.

Comment: It's quite a small company. We all know exactly what gets done by everyone on the team, but I do know that time theft can cost a company a good amount regardless of size. If it's in fact none of my business, however, that's fine too.

Comment: You do not know the agreement between the company and the individual. He may be doing things that are not on your radar

Comment: Is he stealing time from you? How is this affecting you, other than the perceived injustice of it?

Comment: It's literally just perceived injustice at this point.

Comment: Is he *your* supervisor or somebody else's?  How does his behavior affect you?

Comment: @KentAnderson I suspect as much. We have many college-enrolled employees that often need personal time for studies, but also cash flow, so when a single supervisor has racked up 30+ paid "sick days" for the year, it just seems overly excessive (among other exploitations).

Comment: Right.. this was brought to my attention by an employee in accounting who was drafting payroll, we were 100% unsure if this is something you bring to the table or let play out on it's own. And @MonicaCellio, I'm technically supervised by the person above this manager, but it goes without saying they have the ability to make judgment calls too.

Comment: Do you have equity in the company? He could be taking money out of your pocket. BTW, I think someone in accounting has a leg to stand on when it comes to reporting that someone's claims of hours worked look like they may be inaccurate. If people in accounting don't catch that stuff, who will?

Comment: I don't agree with comments none of you business.  If I see someone doing what looks like shoplifting in a store I will report it.  He is not stealing from me and he may in fact be a marketing person for the company with legitimate reason but still I report it.   If I saw a person stuffing reams of paper in briefcase on a regular basis I would report it.

Comment: @Frisbee - agree. These are the types of companies that can't afford to give you a raise because they're not capable of getting rid of people who don't do their job and force everyone else to pick up the slack.

Comment: Is the accounting employee supposed to report payroll anomalies to you? If not there might be problems if you report it. The payroll employee could reasonably ask their own supervisor about it.

Comment: @Frisbee If OP had actually seen or heard of something bad going on, "None of your business" might not be the best approach. However, to continue the shoplifting analogy, OP has seen a customer leaving the store with a bag of groceries. Since he still has money in his wallet, is it safe to assume he stole the bag of groceries? OP simply doesn't know enough of the whole picture to be able to pass judgement. He is just dealing with his perception that someone is getting away with being dishonest. But he doesn't know for sure.

Comment: @KentAnderson Bag of groceries?  Pass judgement?  If I see what looks like an irregularity I report it.   If my neighbor leaves their car door open and I knock on their door to tell them was I passing judgement?  Was it none of my business?

Comment: Calling this "time theft" is slightly ridiculous. More accurate would be to call this behaviour simply "wasting time" or "padding hours". Also, padding time may be acceptable in some shops/circumstances (suppose you did a required work task outside of the office, and padding the clock-in data is the acceptable practice to cover that).

Comment: For all you know, the supervisor has arranged this with your line manager and is just clocking up as agreed to avoid the company dealing with un-necessary admin/paperwork over a pre-arranged agreement....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on your comments under the original question, you are not being adversely affected in your ability to do your job, and your reputation is not being damaged in any way by this individual's actions. By your own admission, you're simply indignant that somebody appears to be getting away with something.

I recommend you step back, give the person the benefit of the doubt, and assume there's a good reason for why he is doing what you perceive he is doing.

From personal experience, life is just happier when you teach yourself to let go of the perceived injustices in the world, trust people until they give you a (real) reason to distrust them, and not worry about injustices you think are happening.

My analogy (and my person challenge to overcome): Yes, we all love it when a police officer stops a solo driver in the carpool lane. But we shouldn't get angry when we see a solo driver over there, we should just keep going and get back to whatever it was we were thinking about a few seconds before.

Comment: And sometimes the people who "are getting away with something" are, in in fact, people who have a medical or personal emergency that their bosses have made accommodations for. Since this is privileged information, you would not have been  told about it.  Assuming the best rather than the worst of people tends to make you happier in the long run.

Comment: Or, in this case, the supervisor might be working on a confidential project, not involving the OP, at home or at some other location.